# White line on top of the screen flickering on 1920x1080

Tags: display

I just installed ubuntu and everything seems to work just fine except for the white line on top of the screen that keeps flickering, especially when I'm using a web browser. I tried to change the resolution and it seems like the problem only persist on 1920x1080.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Is it possible to attach a screenshot so people can identify the problem better?

Comment: It's really hard to take a screenshot, as weird as it may sound it disappears once you press Prt Sc. Its just a thin white line on top of everything that goes away as quickly as it appears.

Comment: Is your system fully updated?

Comment: Yes, it has been updated.

Comment: Did you try to test the monitor on another computer? There are many chances that this is a monitor fault

Comment: I have an asus laptop. Its been working fine on windows.

Comment: You can try plugging in an external monitor and see if it happens there also. If not, in my opinion, something's going on with your laptop display. The fact that the problem doesn't appear on another operating system could be a better, or tampered, display driver.

Comment: Well I added the custom resolution of 1920x1070 and the line has gone.

Comment: In my brand new Chinese laptop (ezbook x4) I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with a new Dell 24'' monitor, which had the white flickering line at the top of the screen.Only when connected to VGA port to my laptop (HDMI worked fine).
Fixed by going into monitor settings (on monitor itself, not from the computer) and pressing "Auto Adjust".